# How to create a Alpha Numeric Sequence in Apex 5.1

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-apex

I want to create a alpha numeric sequence in Apex 5.1
Sequence should be like

AB001
AB002
AB003

Comment: _I want to create a alpha numeric sequence..._ Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @bub
yes bub i tried
First i created a table , after that a numeric sequence but in third step i am not able to create constraint sequence

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the sequence onto the letters.

e.g. `'AB'||seq.nextval`

Comment: Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: I am trying to use it in Oracle Apex to generate the Alpha Numeric sequence

Comment: Below is the code of Triggers which i have used---
create or replace trigger BI_STUDENTS   
  before insert on STUDENTS               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW.STDID is null then 
    select concat('A',STDID_SEQ.nextval) into :NEW.STDID from dual; 
  end if; 
end;

Comment: I have also used SQL Server Approach
Like Creating a simple 
1.Numeric sequence
2.Creating a sequence constraint
3.Pushing the value in Table
But got error-ed out in 2 step only 
Link which i used is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021323/alpha-numeric-sequence-in-sql-server)

Comment: That should work.  I'm guessing you have made your id column type number when it should be type varchar2 and you are getting an conversion error.