# Generate Sequence Code A-Z then 0-9 on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a case to generate sequence ID but alphabet first then numeric  ( `A-Z` then `0-9` ) I see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30021323/2021168)
here and try the solution, but the solution always give me `0-9` first then `A-Z`

```
    WITH seq AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.alpha + y.number + z.number ) AS Id,
        CONVERT(nchar(3), x.alpha + y.number + z.number) AS Result
    FROM 
        (
            VALUES 
            ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9'),
            ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'), 
            ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'), 
            ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z')
        ) x(alpha) ,
        (
            VALUES 
            
            ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'), 
            ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'), 
            ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z'),
              ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')
        ) y(number),
        (
            VALUES 
           
            ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'), 
            ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'), 
            ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z'),  ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')
        ) z(number)
 
)


SELECT *  FROM seq WHERE Id = (SELECT Id + 1 FROM seq WHERE Result = 'A1Z')
```

the Sequence what should generated is :

> AAA,...,AAZ,AA1,...,AA9,ABA,...,ABZ,AB1,..,AB9,...999

sample when I hit the `A1Z` the expected next value is `A11`, but the solution I tried give me `A21` , is the behavior of SQL is start by `0-9` then `A-Z` , how to accomplish my requirement ?

Comment: Add clarity with examples of desired output please.

Comment: What is your starting value, `'AAA'` or `'A'`?

Comment: @Stu so I want AAA,,...AAZ, AA1...AA9, ABA... ABZ, AB1..AB9,...999

Comment: @Larnu my starting value will be AAA

Comment: What happens when you get to the value *after* `999`? Do you start at 'AAA'` again?

Comment: @Larnu the max will be 999 so the sequence will be AAA,,...AAZ, AA1.,..AA9, ABA... ABZ, AB1..AB9,...999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want? Numbers have lower value than letters in T-SQL, so when you order them then `'9'` has a lower number than `'A'`. What you could do, however, is check if the value is a valid `int` value or not, and then order the values that aren't first, and then by the character.

This gives you the following:

```sql
WITH Characters AS(
    SELECT V.C
    FROM (VALUES('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9'),
                ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'), 
                ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'), 
                ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z')) V(C)),
Sequences AS(
    SELECT CONCAT(C1.C,C2.C,C3.C) AS Sequence,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(int,C1.C), C1.C, TRY_CONVERT(int,C2.C), C2.C, TRY_CONVERT(int,C3.C), C3.C) AS RN
    FROM Characters C1
         CROSS JOIN Characters C2
         CROSS JOIN Characters C3)
SELECT *
FROM Sequences;
```

You didn't state where `0` goes, so I *assumed* `'AAZ'`,`'AA0'`, `'AA1'`...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ASCII` function with a simple algorithm in `ORDER BY`, judging the char whether number or letter. if the char is number need to add `43`

because the gap between `Z` (Capital letter) and `0` (first number) is 43, we need to add 43 to the number char to make sure the number is always behind letters.

```
WITH seq AS
(
      
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  IIF(x.alpha LIKE '[A-Z]', ASCII(x.alpha), ASCII(x.alpha) + 43),
                                     IIF(y.number LIKE '[A-Z]', ASCII(y.number), ASCII(y.number) + 43),
                                     IIF(z.number LIKE '[A-Z]', ASCII(z.number), ASCII(z.number) + 43)) AS Id,
        CONVERT(nchar(3), x.alpha + y.number + z.number) AS Result
    FROM 
        (
            VALUES 
            ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'), 
            ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'), 
            ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z'),
            ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')
           
        ) x(alpha) ,
        (
            VALUES 
            
            ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'), 
            ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'), 
            ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z'),
              ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')
        ) y(number),
        (
            VALUES 
           
            ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'), 
            ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'), 
            ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z'), 
            ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')
        ) z(number)
 
)



SELECT *  FROM seq WHERE Id = (SELECT Id + 1 FROM seq WHERE Result = 'A1Z');
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb4952906c2c99292ec890ea126b0b81)